# Showing that a directed graph that has a cycle belongs to NL

Tags: graphs, space-complexity

DCG = { G | Directed graphs that contains a cycle }

How can I proof that DCG belongs to NL?

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St-connectivity?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.